# In React-Table, How to fetch data from api and pass it to subcomponent when expander is clicked ?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm trying to implement a table where there's a more button to load more data from api.

The fetched data will be rendered in a subcomponent.

How to achieve the same using react-table ?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
 <ReactTable
    data={data}
    freezeWhenExpanded={true}
    columns={[
      {
        Header: 'Name',
        accessor: 'name',
        width: 200
      },

      {
        Header: 'Email ID',
        accessor: 'emailId'
      },
      {
        Header: 'Phone',
        accessor: 'phone',
        maxWidth: 150
      },

      {
        expander: true,
        Header: () => <span>More</span>,
        width: 65,
        Expander: ({ isExpanded, ...rest }) => (
          <div>
            {isExpanded ? <span>&#x25B2;</span> : <span>&#x25BC;</span>}
          </div>
        ),
      }
    ]}
    SubComponent={() => (
      <div> fetched data from api to be shown here </div>
    )}
  />
```

Comment: I have got the answer. I'm importing a separate component as subcomponent with lifecycle methods and fetching the data in that container.

Comment: And did that work for you? For me, if i do that in the SubComponent ComponentDidMount, it will trigger unmounting-mounting forever due to SubComponent props changing when fetching data that changes props of the subcomponent